# Is there a limit on the number of operations VBA can perform?

Tags: vba, excel

Inspired by a [puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44997/ane-and-her-block-toys)  I saw online , and since I'm a VBA newbie, I thought it might be an interesting exercise to help me learn how to use `For` loops by making a brute force method to search for solutions to it.

This led to creating a monstrosity that takes ages to partially run and actually won't fully run at all.
All the code is meant to do is print 3 columns of valid combinations

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim j As Long
Dim abc As String
Dim def As String
Dim ghi As String

j = 1

   For a = 1 To 9
    For b = 1 To 9
     For c = 1 To 9
      For d = 1 To 9
       For e = 1 To 9
        For f = 1 To 9
         For g = 1 To 9
          For h = 1 To 9
           For i = 1 To 9
'Line breaks included for ease of reading
            If a = b Or a = c Or a = d Or a = e Or a = f Or a = g Or a = h Or a = i 
            Or b = c Or b = d Or b = e Or b = f Or b = g Or b = h Or b = i 
            Or c = d Or c = e Or c = f Or c = g Or c = h Or c = i 
            Or d = e Or d = f Or d = g Or d = h Or d = i 
            Or e = f Or e = g Or e = h Or e = i 
            Or f = g Or f = h Or f = i 
            Or g = h Or g = i 
            Or h = i Then

           Else
           abc = a & b & c
           def = d & e & f
           ghi = g & h & i

           ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 1).Value = abc
           ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 2).Value = def
           ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 3).Value = ghi

           j = j + 1
           End If

         Next i
        Next h
       Next g
      Next f
     Next e
    Next d
   Next c
  Next b
 Next a
End Sub
```

This obviously involves lots of simple operations, and results in variously (Not Responding) messages or it just doesn't run. Was it possible to tell before clicking "Go" that that would be the case?

My job has me working on, and adding to, spread sheets that perform lots of operations on other spread sheets with conceivably hundreds of thousands of data items in each. Continuing to add functionality to these files may or may not be sustainable, I need to know how to tell before I sink time into further development.

Is there a hard limit to what can be done with VBA in terms of volumes/numbers of operations? Is there a tool that will estimate the viability of a macro actually running to completion? A heuristic commonly employed in industry?

Basically, what methods or tools exist to inform as to whether the demands of a macro or series of macros will exceed available memory?

Thanks

Comment: This question may be better suited for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: "Not responding" and exceeding available memory are very different things. No, they generally can't be predicted beforehand, and no, they are not specific to VBA. If you want to know why a Windows program may freeze on a long running sub, you should read about message loops. If you want to avoid this effect in this particular macro, call `DoEvents` every so often.

Comment: up to 64K of compiled code in a single procedure http://excel.tips.net/T003174_Maximum_Length_Limit_for_a_Macro.html

Comment: I don't think you need to check the lot like that, with some `GoTo`s you could say, after `for b=.....`  `if b=a then goto next_b_val`, maybe?

Comment: @GSerg or just disable `Application.ScreenUpdating` (and re-enable it after); `DoEvents` will keep the host responsive, but will also make your monster loop take much longer to complete.

Comment: @Slai whoever reading this comment without clicking the link might actually think 63K of compiled code in a single procedure is "fine". Note to the reader: ***IT ISN'T***.

Comment: This code performs 21.1 billion boolean comparisons.  That will take some time. My machine will do roughly 150 million per second. That's about 2 and a half minutes for the `If` tests ***alone***. Add that to the 362,880 cells that you're writing individually, and I'm guessing you aren't waiting long enough for it to complete.  This would seem to indicate that "a brute force method" probably isn't the best solution to the problem.

Comment: @Mat'sMug year ago I converted a VBA template to C# Add-In. The VBA version has Sub split into 47 Subs of If-ElseIf statements (now I realize why it was split :] ), but it ran almost as fast as the C# version (about a second). It's not "fine", but just example that ~3MB of VBA source code (somehow ~5.5 MB compiled) can be a thing used for many years without noticeable problems.

Answer (score 1):

You should attempt to do a tiny bit of maths before you begin.

Your code generates all the permutations of 9 thing taken 9 at a time.  Before you begin, you know this this will fill *362880* rows;  so the code should work.

A separate issue is how much time will it take, and is this the most efficient method .

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but can it be tackled by just looping the numbers?  Something along these lines, is checking the 1st char against the rest

```
Dim l As Long
Dim i As Integer

For l = 11111111 To 99999999
    For i = 2 To 8
        DoEvents
        If (Mid(l, i, 1) <> Mid(l, 1, 1)) Then
            Debug.Print l
        End If
    Next i
Next l
```